# How to show Column Header of empty collection

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How to show the Column Headers for a empty collection which has some properties for its column. The properties of that collection will be known only in run time. So the Datagrid's AutoGenerateColumns set to True.

**Update:**

It was a bug with .Net framework 4.0. When i check with SP1 of VS2010 it was fixed.

How do handle this?

Comment: Can you not handle [`DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) event and give it some header?

Comment: @dkozl: I have already checked that, It was not invoked for empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to test your datasource and if empty add a null data item to give you the headers, then set row[0].IsVisible = false to hide the row. You would need to undo this when you get data that has rows